# Clear page data without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple game that produces a random number and takes a user input where the user attempts to guess the number, and the code appends each user guess to a list so they know which numbers they've guessed. There is also a "new game" (.new) link up top that the user can hit at any time to start over. Currently I have the following js:

```
/*--- Reset game ---*/
$(".new").click(function() {
   location.reload();
});
```

While this works, I would prefer to change the operation so that the page doesn't need to refresh, but rather resets the code to the beginning (i.e. produces a new random number, clears the list items, etc.)

Not sure how to go about doing this. Any Ideas?

Comment: How did you implement the list? A lot of code looks missing here.

Comment: show all of the relevant code, not just the page reloading function

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code, but it should be easy as resetting the variables back to their opening states on click of the `new` button. You may possibly need to use [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) to clear out some HTML too.

Comment: Wherever you generate that random number assign it to null or something default on this click event

Comment: Basically, instead of calling `location.reload()`, which re-loads the page, you'd do something else.  Set form elements to empty values, remove contents from other elements, etc.  We can't know what you would need to do, because you haven't shown it to us.  But basically, if you want to do something other than reload the page, then you'd replace the code which reloads the page with the code which does that other thing.

Comment: When assigning initial values to lists and other variables, put it in a function (all the initialization). And just call that function on that click. You can clear some html tags if needed as well. like `$("#some_stuff").text("")`

Comment: Here's a codepen to my full code. I have tried to implement some of the changes suggested but to no avail.

https://codepen.io/caulds989/pen/rebKeV?editors=1010#anon-login

As you can see the ```li```'s are generated via jquery as at the start of the the game there are no guesses. Any further help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a function that builds the random number and the call it every time new game is clicked. 
So for example have a function called `generateRandomNumber()` and use it the following way:

```
/*--- Reset game ---*/
$(".new").click(function() {
    generateRandomNumber(); //Function to start everything from the beginning
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a list, and when user checks their guess, add an element to the list. For the new, just get all the li elements from the list and remove them.

Two buttons, `new` and `check`, and two click events. I've made a quick sketch:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVKJB

You could complete it with the random number generation, validation and stuff.